# Vim: How to use local directory .vimrc to override key mapping defined by file type <buffer> map?

Tags: vim

I have a key mapping in
`~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`

```
nnoremap <buffer> <C-D> : ! cc % && ./a.out <CR>
```

I want create a local configuration `project/.vimrc` to override the old mapping

```
nnoremap <C-D> : ! cc % -lncurses && ./a.out <CR>
```

But it not work.

I try

1. in previous example, the local map is global, it is override by the <buffer> mapping.
2. in local .vimrc , **map <buffer> <C-D> ...** ,
   but it only override the key mapping of first opened file.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit autocommands should be executed after the content of `after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
augroup c_overrides
autocmd!
autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.c nnoremap ...
augroup END
```

or:

```
augroup c_overrides
autocmd!
autocmd! FileType c nnoremap ...
augroup END
```

But what you should really do is put your project-specific commands in `Makefile` and use `:make %` in every project.

See `:help :make`.

Comment: Thanks! That is my need. I just want a quickly command to run.  Makefile is used for larger project.